# SAML consumer URL

Tags: saml-2.0

We are implementing SAML integration and  I am the service provider and my identity provider is asking me to send "SAML Consumer URL" and "RelayState"

I would need help to understand what is SAML consumer URL & RelayState and how do I get/generate it for my application.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

TLDR, AssertionConsumerUrl (ACS) endpoint is SAML protocol endpoint, RelayState is like cross-domain cookie, used to coordinate messages and actions of IdPs and SPs.

In `5.1.Web Browser SSO Profile` of [SAML 2.0 Technical Review](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.1.Web%20Browser%20SSO%20Profile%7Coutline), it will give you a general understanding of how the flow goes.

Down to the SSO implementation, for example `Shibboleth`, this [FlowAndConfig doc](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/FlowsAndConfig) details the SSO flow pretty well.

In `2. SP Determines IdP and Issues Authentication Request`:

> Cookie Set by SP
>
> During this step, the SP will preserve the original
>   resource requested by the browser using a "relay state" mechanism,
>   which is configured by a relayState property on the `<SessionInitiator>`
>   element. The default mechanism does not rely on a cookie any longer,
>   but many systems do, and send a state management cookie containing the
>   resource URL to the client along with the request prepared for the IdP
>   or DS/WAYF.

In `5. Back to the SP`:

> The browser delivers the response from the IdP to an Assertion Consumer Service endpoint at the SP.

`relay state` info returned from IdP to SP

> Cookie Read by SP
>
> The "relay state" information returned by the IdP, if any, will have
>   been created by the SP and if using a cookie, will point to a
>   specially named cookie that should accompany the authentication
>   response supplied to the ACS endpoint in this step. This is the cookie
>   set in Step 2 above. If this cookie is missing (or if no relay state
>   exists at all), the associated application's homeURL property is
>   substituted as a fall back.

Also, Shibboleth has some wiki for those two terms as well.

- [AssertionConsumerService concept](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/AssertionConsumerService)
- [RelayState concept](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB/RelayState)

Hope it helps!